# Create Photo grid view like Samsung Galaxy Grand

Tags: android

How to Create Photo Grid View Like Samsung galaxy grand In android?

I want to create Photo Grid view (Gallery) same as the Galaxy grand in android.

There is any possiblity To Create Custom Photo Gallary like Samsung Galaxy Grand In android.

Answer (score 0):

You can take idea from Custom GridView with multiple option selection option. There is an open source project in Github.

https://github.com/paramvir-b/AndroidGridViewCompatLib

Comment: This is for select multiple item in gallary.

Comment: I want to create custom photo gallay like same as the Samsung galaxy grand?

Comment: I think you have got a better answer to your same duplicate question and now also you have got a decent answer for you duplicate question.You can try atleast and then move on to SAMSUNG lookalike gallery.